# Linux IPC mechanism for simultaneous event trigger in multiple processes?

Tags: c++, linux, multiprocessing, ipc

I am writing data acquisition software for multiple USB connected cameras in C++. Each camera has its own process instance, where each process initializes the camera, waits for the trigger and start streaming frames to disk, like this:

```
initialize camera
...
wait for recording trigger
while (recording) {
    get_frames
}
```

What kind of IPC should I use in order to toggle the recording flag in all processes **as simultaneously as possible**?

The trigger can be sent from another process (e.g. keyboard monitoring or hardware button on GPIO pins of Raspberry Pi, for example). Is it possible to quantify/measure how synchronously these events occur in each process?

Comment: You can do this with System V semaphores (not Posix semaphores). There is an operation to increment semaphore value by an arbitrary number. Just increment it by the number of cameras, this will wake up all processes waiting on the semaphore.

Comment: You could also use `eventfd()` in semaphore mode if all the processes can be given a file descriptor in common.

Comment: named semaphores should work: https://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview